# Getting a pure list out of 'pyparsing.ParseResults'

Tags: python, pyparsing

I'm currently trying to get a result from pyparsing as a pure list so I can flatten it. I read in the documentation that

> ParseResults can also be converted to an ordinary list of strings by calling asList(). Note that this will strip the results of any field names that have been defined for any embedded parse elements. (The pprint module is especially good at printing out the nested contents given by asList().)

So I tried defining a `setParseAction` where I work on the ParseResult

what I get is:

```
>>> print type(tokens.args[0])
 <class 'pyparsing.ParseResults'>
>>> print type(tokens.args[0].asList)
 <type 'instancemethod'>
```

But I was expecting/needing the last one to be of type list. I must be missing something important when using `asList()` here.

Dietmar

PS: Here a MTC of what the tokens actually look like:

```
>>> print tokens.args[0]
['foo1', ['xxx'], ',', 'graphics={', 'bar1', ['xxx,yyy'], ',', 'bar2', 
['xxx,yyy'], ',', 'bar3', ['xxx,yyy,', 'zzz=baz', ['xxx,yyy']], '}']
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`tokens.args[0].asList` is a function. `tokens.args[0].asList()` is a call to that function (with no arguments beyond the `self` argument). It seems that you would like to know the type of that latter expression.

Answer (score 5):

Can you try

```
 print type(tokens.args[0].asList())
```